# CTRL down on reconnect - Is this a bug in Remote Desktop?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, rdp, bug

I stumbled upon a weird problem when using RDP and it seems to be reproducible in my environment:

- Connect (in my case from Windows 7) to a remote Windows system (here Windows 2012)
- Open up a browser (Chrome) on the remote system and go to an arbitrary web page with some links on it
- Then look the screen on your local Windows and wait until the screen goes off and energy saving kicks in
- Unlock your local Windows and go back to the remote browser in the RDP session
- Click a link

At this point any mouse click on a link opens up a new tab, it behaves like the CTRL key is pressed all the time. You can as well open up Windows Explorer and click on some files, they will all be selected, just like they would when CTRL is pressed. Can anybody confirm that?

Comment: It isn't uncommon for the remote session to become confused about which modifier keys are currently active, though I don't recall encountering this particular variant before.  Does the problem go away if you push and release the control key(s)?

Comment: No, it does not, but when you kill the session and reconnect, the problem disappears.